# angular5 project draggable element supernatant has wrong position

Tags: angular, draggable

My project is based on Angular5.1. And I have a component `<legacy-pods>`. In anothor page it is used by `<legacy-pods></legacy-pods>`. When I add atribute `draggable` on it, it looks like `<legacy-pods draggable="true"></legacy-pods>`. On the page in chrome, this element can be draged. But the supernatant is not at the correct position. Like this
[image]

I dont't know if that is the problem about `css` style or some others. May be caused by virtual dom `legacy-pod`?